# AllenNLP Server: pip is looking at multiple versions of each package

Tags: allennlp

Within my Conda environment with Python 3.6.9, I've installed AllenNLP 9.2.0. I tried to install AllenNLP Server following the instruction from https://github.com/allenai/allennlp-server by running `pip install --editable .`

However, [the installation procedure never finished as the compatibility checks with several modules](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rLHrT.png), e.g. `pip is looking at multiple versions of tqdm to determine which version is compatible with other requirements. This could take a while. Collecting tqdm>=4.19`

Does anybody know what happens here? Should I add more restrictions to steup.py in AllenNLP server? However, there is any code included in such file.

Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: AllenNLP 9.2.0 does not exist. Could you clarify which version you're installing?

Comment: While I do not have the exact same warning message, I have had multiple instances where installing allennlp via conda is taking extremely long to resolve package versions (>4 hours). On the other hand a pip installation takes less than 5 minutes.

Answer (score 0):

I just tried it with AllenNLP 2.0.1 (the latest), and while it takes a long time, it does eventually resolve the packages.

That said, I would recommend two things:

1. Use Python 3.8 instead.
2. If it still doesn't work, specify a version of `tqdm` tightly in the requirements. My version automatically picked `tqdm==4.56.2`, just or reference.